# Show that for all integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that for all integers **n ≥ 1** applies that **$5|2^{3n} - 3^{n}$**

can anyone help?

Comment: $2^{3n}-3^n=8^n-3^n=(8-3)(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 8^{n-1-i}3^i)$

Answer (score 0):

It is a one line proof:
$$2^{3n}-3^n=8^n-3^n\equiv 3^n-3^n\equiv 0 \mod 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

$2^{3n}=8^n$

$a^n-b^n=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+b^{n-1}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You could prove it by mathematical induction using

$2^{3(n+1)}-3^{n+1}=8\times2^{3n}-3\times3^n=5\times2^{3n}+3(2^{3n}-3^n)$

Comment: Other answers use induction implicitly